# Accelerating MySQL Insert Performance?

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance, load-data-infile

There is the need to insert more than 10M records at minimum time in an indexed table. These 10M records are a result of a cursor running within a stored procedure. Currently, it takes approximately 50min to insert all data into the table.

What would you recommend to accelerate its performance? Another option is LOAD DATA INFILE, but again would you export the query results into a temporary file, so it can be inserted fast enough?

Due to the volume of data, we thought to decouple the process and transfer responsibility to MySQL rather putting additional stress to the PHP Connector. Is it a better way to do?

All recommendations are more than welcome. Thank you!

A sample of the cursor is the following:

```
--- MyISAM EXAMPLE
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS createSegmentMyISAM;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE createSegmentMyISAM(IN accountId INT(11), setId INT(11), volume INT(11))
BEGIN
DECLARE complete INT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE field_a VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE field_b VARCHAR(254);
DECLARE field_c VARCHAR(35);
DECLARE field_d VARCHAR(35);

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT sb.`field_a`,
           sb.`field_b`,
           sb.`field_c`,
           sb.`field_d`
    FROM   `mydb`.`mytable` sb 
    WHERE  sb.`tbl2` IN (SELECT dm.`field_e` 
                           FROM   `mydb`.`tbl3` dm 
                                  INNER JOIN `mydb`.`tbl4` st 
                                          ON dm.`set_id` = st.`set_id` 
                           WHERE  st.set_id = setId) 
    LIMIT  0, volume;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET complete = TRUE; 

OPEN cur;

read_loop: LOOP

    FETCH cur INTO field_a, field_b, field_c, field_d;

    IF complete THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO `mydb`.`temp` (fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD) VALUES (field_a, field_b, field_c, field_d);

END LOOP;

CLOSE cur;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Do you keep adding 10M rows into one huge table? Can you afford to drop indexes while it inserts?

Comment: How many indexes are involved in the update? I see the word ISAM which implies indexes to me.  Indexes slow insert operations

Comment: Have you tried replacing your stored procedure by a single INSERT [...] SELECT statement?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, guys! I dropped the Indexes, used LOAD DATA INFILE and managed to insert 10M rows in 3min, 27secs. The target tables will be empty, as new will be created when the operation is initialised. For large data manipulation, do you reckon this approach is best? RE: MyISAM, I tried to change the engine and experiment, so I can see whether there is any improvement in performance.